# Networked CUDA GPU

Tags: cuda, cloud

Is it possible for multiple low-end computers to each make CUDA calls to a GPU located on a central server in a request/response over the cloud scenario? To make it as if these low-end computers possess a "virtual" GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similiar problem to solve.

The database was living in the low end machine and I had a cluster of GPUs in my disposal on the local network.

I made a small client (on the low end machine) to parse the database, serialize the data with [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and send them to the server with [zmq sockets](http://www.zeromq.org/). For data distribution you can have asynchrouns publisher/subscriber sockets.

On the server side you deserialize the data and you have the CUDA program to run the calculations (it can also be a daemonized application so you dont have to fire it up yourself every time).

Once the data is ready on the server you can issue a synchronous message (request/reply socket) from the client and when the server receives the message it calls a function wrapper to the CUDA kernel.

If you need to process the results back on the client you can follow the reverse route to send the data back to the client.

If the data is already in the server, its even easier. You only need the request/reply socket to send a message and call the function.

Check the zmq manual, they have a lot of examples in many programming languages.